# appendbytes with mp4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mp4

Hi I have a flash as3 player that is playing flv files using appendbytes.

I have searched the web for many hours on how to stream a mp4 using appendbytes.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Just using Netstream is not an option as we need progressive download seeking.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I've found is using the [SoundLoaderContext](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundLoaderContext.html), and setting the first argument to be whatever time you want to spend buffering.

I've researched the "loadCompressedDataFromByteArray" and "loadPCMFromByteArray " methods in the Sound class, but the solution would be to buffer a certain amount of sound and then load it.

Found this [sample code](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=156066):

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundLoaderContext;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var s:Sound = new Sound();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("trackName.mp4");
var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(8000, true);
s.load(req, context);
s.play();
```